# How to do one GetItems call to SharePoint then filter the items inside the workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have this SharePoint list named "WorkFlow Groups", which contain title and email, as follow:

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1709218365190.png]

Now I want to do a call to get all the items, then filter the items by the Title to get the email (the "WorkFlow Group" field), i tried the following but did not work:

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1709218502966.png]

[image: johnjohnPter_2-1709218564601.png]

[image]

[image]

[image]

but I will get null value... any advice?

Comment: Why are you using Select action again? Also, use `GroupEmail` instead of `WorkFlowGroup` in compose action formula.

Comment: Try solution given below without additional "select" action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, no need to use the "Select" action in this case, use flow like:

[image]

**Expression used in compose**:

```
body('Filter_array')[0]?['WorkFlowGroup']
```

Where `WorkFlowGroup` is an **internal name** of your column in SharePoint list. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

---

If you want to use "Select" action for any other reasons:

First, change the value of the `GroupEmail` key in the Map field (right hand side) of "Select" action to:

```
item()['WorkflowGroup']
```

then try using expression like below for compose action:

```
body('Select')[0]?['GroupEmail']
```

Comment: you are correct no need to do extra select.. thanks for the help